# Including wp-config.local.php file

Tags: ddev

I have followed the setup instruction for local development of a wordpress project.

I am wanting to define some additional constants in wp-config.php, but referring to the documentation at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#adding-configuration, it suggests loading a wp-config-local.php after wp-config-ddev.php.

If the wp-config.php is managed by ddev, and changes there are overwritten on 'ddev start', what is the recommended way to include a wp-config-local.php to make my required changes?

I can remove the '#ddev-generated: Automatically generated WordPress settings file.' to enable changes to the wp-config.php file, but this doesn't seem to align with the suggested approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is that you look at the WP config file that is *not* managed by DDEV, the one that includes the `wp-config-ddev.php`. In *that* file, after `wp-config-ddev.php` is included, include your `wp-config-local.php`. There are many ways to do this depending on the type of WP layout you have... but if WordPress is working for you, then `wp-confid-ddev.php` is being included somewhere. Figure out where, and right after it gets loaded, load the configuration you want to add.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however ddev has added the below comment at the top of the wp-config.php file and this file is where the wp-config-ddev.php is being required (all configured when i ran through the wordpress quickstart)

/**
 * ddev manages this file and may delete or overwrite the file unless this comment is removed.
 * It is recommended that you leave this file alone.
*/
So my only option is to remove the above comment, so ddev no longer manages the wp-config.php file and require my wp-config.local.php in there. Is that correct?

Comment: Probably normal is just to provide your own wp-config.php, which is the same as removing the `#ddev-generated`.